# Using Moq to provide a concrete object that leverages a mock

Tags: c#, moq

I have an interface `IConfig` that has several methods for accessing config values.

A concrete implementation would look something like this

```
// Sync versions
public String GetValue(ISetting) => this.GetConfigValue(ISetting.StringValue);
public Double GetValue(ISetting) => this.GetConfigValue(ISetting.DoubleValue);

// Async versions
public Task<String> GetValueAsync(ISetting) => this.GetConfigValueAsync(ISetting.StringValue);
public Task<Double> GetValueAsync(ISetting) => this.GetConfigValueAsync(ISetting.DoubleValue);

private IConfigValue GetValue(ISetting setting) {
...
}

private async Task<IConfigValue> GetValueAsync(ISetting setting) {
...
}
```

Now.

For testing purposes I would like for the tests to inherit from a class, that provides easy ways to mock a config value without having to concern the test writer with which type the setting is, and whether it will be resolved in a sync or async fashion.

In particular: Since we use strict mocking, if the test writer had to just mock the IConfig interface, then they would need to be aware of whether the config values were accessed in sync or async fashion.

I thought I would be clever and do something like this:

- Create a class that implements IConfig
- Have it leverage an interface that has a Task GetValueAsync method
- Make methods on my class that mock return values for calling that class
- Provide my class as the resolved object for IConfig

...so something like the below.

But this seems somewhat inelegant

Is there a good/better way to do this?

```
public interface IAsyncConfigValueProvider
{
  Task<IConfigValue> GetValueAsync(ISetting setting);
}

protected void SetConfigValue(ISetting setting, String s)
{
    this.AutoMock.Mock<IAsyncConfigValueProvider>().Setup(c => c.GetValueAsync(setting)).ReturnsAsync(new ConfigValue(s)):
}


public class FakeConfig : IConfig
{
  public String GetValue(ISetting) => this.GetConfigValue(ISetting.StringValue);
  public Task<String> GetValueAsync(ISetting) => this.GetConfigValueAsync(ISetting.StringValue);
  
  private Task<IConfigValue> GetConfigValueAsync(ISetting setting)
  {
    return this.AutoMock.Resolve<IAsyncConfigValueProvider>(setting)
  }

  private IConfigValue GetConfigValue(ISetting setting)
  {
    // Implement via task factory and this.GetConfigValueAsync
  }
}

public class TestBase {

  public TestBase() 
  {
    // ...
    this.AutoMock.Provide<IConfig>(new FakeConfig(this.AutoMock));
    // ...
  }
}
```